# javafx rotatetransition appearance different

Tags: java, windows, javafx

I am developing an application, in which rotatetransition is used, along with other transitions.  On my local development machine, it appears as expected.  I have tested this on several VMs: Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 8.  It appears normal in all but XP and 7, when my local machine is 7.  I am using the same jre for all VMs and local machine, 8.25.  On XP and 7 VMs, when the rotate transition is performed, the node being rotated does not rotate, instead it moves to the upper left corner of the parent node.  I have checked javafx version on these machines, and it the jre version.  The code for the transition is very simple:

```
TranslateTransition translate = 
          new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), tileButton);
  translate.setByX(x);
  translate.setByY(y);
  ScaleTransition scale = 
          new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(300), tileButton);
  scale.setByX(scaleX);
  scale.setByY(scaleY);
  scale.autoReverseProperty();
  PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(200));
  RotateTransition rotator = 
          new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(600), tileButton);
  rotator.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
  rotator.setFromAngle(0);
  rotator.setToAngle(180);
  rotator.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
  rotator.setCycleCount(1);
  ParallelTransition parallel = new ParallelTransition(translate, scale);
  SequentialTransition transition = 
          new SequentialTransition(parallel, pause, rotator);
  transition.play();
```

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be support for 3d graphics.  To resolve this, I just changed it a little:

```
SequentialTransition transition;
  if(Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D))   
     transition = new SequentialTransition(parallel, pause, rotator);
  else
     transition = new SequentialTransition(parallel);
```